squid block website range doesn't work like always
Just wish to block access to my internal network from "squid request" like routers IDRAC but squid is super nerd enough that can't block request to 192.168.8.1 or 192.168.22.1. Even deny doesn't work, moving to one place to another rules to rewrite them doesn't work. Access is limited to IP address by firewall: 22.33.44.55 so simple and so complicated. Guess that maybe "Arch Linux" doesn't install something but when remove allow its show deny page.
#acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10     # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
#acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16    # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src fc00::/7          # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10         # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 22.33.44.55

acl localnet2 src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet2 src 10.0.0.0/8        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet2 src 100.64.0.0/10     # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet2 src 169.254.0.0/16    # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet2 src 172.16.0.0/12     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet2 src 192.168.0.0/16        # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet2 src fc00::/7          # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet2 src fe80::/10         # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# For example, to allow access from your local networks, you may uncomment the
# following rule (and/or add rules that match your definition of "local"):
http_access allow localnet

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# This default configuration only allows localhost requests because a more
# permissive Squid installation could introduce new attack vectors into the
# network by proxying external TCP connections to unprotected services.
http_access allow localhost

# The two deny rules below are unnecessary in this default configuration
# because they are followed by a "deny all" rule. However, they may become
# critically important when you start allowing external requests below them.

# Protect web applications running on the same server as Squid. They often
# assume that only local users can access them at "localhost" ports.
http_access deny to_localhost

# Protect cloud servers that provide local users with sensitive info about
# their server via certain well-known link-local (a.k.a. APIPA) addresses.
http_access deny to_linklocal

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

acl toblock dstdomain asusrouter.com
http_access deny toblock

http_access deny localnet2


# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all


To block access to local network change src to dst as you try to access local to not from
# ip to access to proxy
acl localnet0 src 22.33.44.55

# block destination i.e router
acl localnet3 dst 192.168.5.1   

#allow connect from block connect to 
http_access allow localnet0 !localnet3

sudo squid -k reconfigure
